# "Towards the past" or "in the past"?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

Roots of the India-Pakistan conflict can be found in a shared attitude of derision towards the past.

What difference is the usage of "towards" instead of "in" making here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a shared attitude of derision towards the past

This means that at some time *after* whenever *the past* is, they both had a negative view of the past. Their derision was directed at the past; it was pointed *towards* the past.

> a shared attitude of derision in the past.

This does not mean the same thing. This suggests that they both had some derision towards something, unclear what, but they had this shared attitude at some time in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Here towards is used as a preposition meaning **in relation to somebody/something**

> e.g Our attitude towards humanity.

Roots of the India-Pakistan conflict can be found in a shared attitude of derision towards the past. It implies both the countries still have an attitude of derision in relation to their past.

> Roots of the India-Pakistan conflict can be found in a shared attitude of derision **in** the past.

implies both the countries had an attitude of derision in the past, and this attitude of derision may not be related to their past.